# proc sql left join based on condition with missing values

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to combine two tables using left join for Reconciliation and there are two variables which I want to use for match condition. However, there is an additional requirement for one of the matched variable. If there is a match for second variable then pull that row from second table, if not then put the corresponding second value as missing and still extract other variables from the second table. But I am getting missing values if no match exist for second var. I know this is natural sql behavior. But I just want to try if anything can be done.

Here is a sample code:

```
    data a;
     subj=1; dat="01jan2022"d; output;
     subj=1; dat="01feb2022"d; output;
     subj=1; dat="05mar2022"d; output;
     subj=2; dat="10may2022"d; output;
     subj=2; dat="11jun2022"d; output;
    run;
    
    data b;
     subj=1; dat_new="01jan2022"d; other_var=1; output;
     subj=1; dat_new="01feb2022"d; other_var=2; output;
     subj=1; dat_new="05mar2022"d; other_var=3; output;
     subj=2; dat_new=.; other_var=11; output;
     subj=2; dat_new="11jun2022"d; other_var=21; output;
    run;
    
    proc sql;
    create table ab_reconciliation
    as
    select a.subj, a.dat format=date9., b.dat_new format=date9., b.other_var
    from a as t1
    left join b as t2
    on t1.subj=t2.subj
    and dat=dat_new; 
    quit;
```

**Output I am getting**

[image: Output I have]

**Output I want**

[image]

Appreciate your help!

Comment: How did you decide that you wanted the observation with OTHER_VAR=11 to match with the 10MAY date instead of with the 11JUN date?

Comment: This is the structure of data we have for Reconciliation. It's not ideal but sometimes it gets complicated. 11 jun already has a match so , I am not considering it again.. However, I found a work around . I am dividing the dataset b into two sub datasets b1, b2. one with dat_new=. and other non-missing. Then separately merging a with b1 with dat condition and b2 without dat.. I tried case statement in left join but did't give proper results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you might consider is just INTERLEAVING the observations by ID and DATE and just using the latest value of OTHER_VAR on the dates from A.

So if you have this input data:

```
data a;
  input subj dat :date.;
  format dat date9.;
cards;
 1 01JAN2022
 1 01FEB2022
 1 05MAR2022
 2 10MAY2022
 2 11JUN2022
;

data b;
  input subj dat_new :date. other_var;
  format dat_new date9.;
cards;
 1 01JAN2022 1
 1 01FEB2022 2
 1 05MAR2022 3
 2         . 11
 2 11JUN2022 21
;
```

You can combine them like this:

```
data want;
  set b(in=inb rename=(dat_new=dat)) a(in=ina) ;
  by subj dat;
  if first.id then other=.;
  if inb then other=other_var;
  retain other;
  if ina ;
  drop other_var ;
  rename other=other_var;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, seems a good approach. I just need to fit it into my code as there are close to 100 variables. Appreciate your response.